# Plain javascript audio player not working on mobile phone

Tags: javascript

I was coding a simple audio player with plain javascript. when i test it in my laptop work fine but when i access it from phone isnt work.
my source code:

```
    window.addEventListener("resize", resizeAud, false);
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {


audEl = document.querySelector("#audioElement"); // Audio Element
if (audEl) {
    audEl.removeAttribute("controls");
    audEl.load();
    // Resize audio player on load window //
        resizeAud();
        document.querySelector("#tc3").addEventListener("click", function() {
            setTimeout(resizeAud, 10);
        });

    /*############################################################################################*\
    |*#                                                                                          #*|   
    |*#                                 # ADDeVENTLISTENER #                                     #*|
    |*#                                                                                          #*|
    |*############################################################################################*/

    // Toggle sound details //
    document.querySelector(".show-snd-d").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        document.querySelector(".snd-detail").classList.toggle("active-snd-detail");
    });

    // Hide sound detail on click outside //
    document.querySelector("html").addEventListener("click", function() {
        document.querySelector(".snd-detail").classList.remove("active-snd-detail");
    });


    // Rest show sound detail on click inside //
    document.querySelector(".snd-detail").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    // Toggle sound playlist for mobile screen < 768px //
    document.querySelector(".show-list").addEventListener("click", function() {
        document.querySelector("#snd-list").classList.toggle("active-snd-list");
    });

    // is mouse down or up on ".git" element//
    var isDown = false; // default mouse is up
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
        if (e.target.classList.contains("progressbar") || e.target.classList.contains("heared")) {isDown="progressbar"}
        else if (e.target.classList.contains("snd-volume")
                 || e.target.classList.contains("volume-pro")
                 || e.target.classList.contains("pro")) {isDown="volPro"}
        else {isDown=false}
    });
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
        isDown = false; // is mouseup
    });

    // Change progressbar width on click //
    document.querySelector(".proAna").addEventListener("click", (e) => { reportPro(e); });
    // Change progressbar width on mousedown and move at the same time //
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => { (isDown=="progressbar")?reportPro(e):false; });
    // Change progrssbar on timeupdate
    audEl.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            reportPro("timeupdate");
        },10);
    })
    // init play to 0 on audio ended
    audEl.addEventListener("ended", () => {togglePlay("manual");});

    // Change volumebar height on click //
    document.querySelector(".volume-pro").addEventListener("click", (e) => { reportVol(e); });
    // Change volumebar height on mousedown and move at the same time //
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => { (isDown=="volPro")?reportVol(e):false; });
    // Toggle mute on click on mute button
    document.querySelector(".mute").addEventListener("click", () => { reportVol("mute"); })

    // backward audio //
    document.querySelector(".backward").addEventListener("click", () => { wardAud("backward"); });
    // Toggle play audio //
    document.querySelector(".play-snd").addEventListener("click", togglePlay);
    // forward audio //
    document.querySelector(".forward").addEventListener("click", () => { wardAud("forward"); });
}
}, false);


/*############################################################################################*\
|*#                                                                                          #*|   
|*#                                 # FUNCTIONS #                                            #*|
|*#                                                                                          #*|
|*############################################################################################*/
var audEl = document.querySelector("#audioElement");
// Report progressbar width one click,timeupdate or mouse (down + move) //
if (audEl) {
function reportPro(event) {

    var newWid;
    var duration = !isNaN(audEl.duration)?audEl.duration:0;
    var prWidth = document.querySelector(".progressbar").offsetWidth;

    if (event!="timeupdate") {
        event.preventDefault();
        var bounds = document.querySelector(".progressbar").getBoundingClientRect();
        var x = event.clientX - bounds.left;

        if (x>prWidth) {newWid=prWidth}
        else if(x<=0){newWid=0}
        else {newWid=(x)}

        audEl.currentTime = (newWid/prWidth)*duration;
    }
    var current = audEl.currentTime;
    newWid = (current/duration)*100;
    document.querySelector(".heared").style.width = newWid+"%";
    document.querySelector(".sure").innerHTML = secondsToHms(current)+" / "+secondsToHms(duration);

}

//Convert seconds to h-m-s
function secondsToHms(d) {
    d = Number(d);

    var h = Math.floor(d / 3600);
    var m = Math.floor(d % 3600 / 60);
    var s = Math.floor(d % 3600 % 60);

    return ((h>0)?h+":":"")
          +((h>0)?((m<10)?"0"+m:m):((m>0)?m:"0"))+":"
          +((s<10)?"0"+s:s);
}

// Change volumebar height function //
function reportVol(event) {
    var volHeight = document.querySelector(".volume-pro").offsetHeight;
    
    if (event=="mute") {
        if (audEl.muted) {
            audEl.muted = false;
            bottom = audEl.volume*100;
        }else{
            audEl.muted = true;
            bottom = 0;
        }
        var muteIcon = document.querySelector(".mute").childNodes[0];
        muteIcon.classList.contains("fa-volume-up")? muteIcon.rempClass("fa-volume-up","fa-volume-mute")
                                                   : muteIcon.rempClass("fa-volume-mute","fa-volume-up");


    }else{
        event.preventDefault();
        var bounds = document.querySelector(".volume-pro").getBoundingClientRect();
        var y = bounds.bottom - event.clientY;

        if ((y)>volHeight) {bottom=volHeight}
        else if((y)<=0){bottom=0}
        else {bottom=(y)}


        bottom = (bottom/volHeight)*100;
        audEl.volume = bottom/100;
    }

    document.querySelector(".pro").style.height = bottom+"%";
}

// Toggle Play Function //
function togglePlay(type="") {
    var playBut = document.querySelector(".play-snd");
    var playIcon = playBut.childNodes[0]; // icon element

    if (type=="manual") {
        audEl.currentTime = 0;
        audEl.pause();
    }else if(type=="ward"){
        audEl.play();
    }else{
        (audEl.paused)?audEl.play():audEl.pause(); // Toggle play audio
    }
    // toggle play pause icon
    (!audEl.paused)? playIcon.rempClass("fa-play","fa-pause")+playBut.classList.add("active-play-snd")
                   : playIcon.rempClass("fa-pause","fa-play")+playBut.classList.remove("active-play-snd");
}

// backward and award function //
function wardAud(wardType,elId="") {
    var sndList = document.getElementsByClassName("snd-item");
    var newActive;
    for (var i=0; i < sndList.length; i++) {
        if (sndList[i].classList.contains("active-snd")) { var activeItem = i; }
    }
    if (wardType=="backward") {
        newActive = (activeItem!=0)? sndList[activeItem-1]:false;
    }else if (wardType=="forward"){
        newActive = (activeItem!=(sndList.length-1))? sndList[activeItem+1]:false;
    }else if (wardType=="specific") {
        newActive = sndList[elId];
        console.log(elId);
    }

    if(newActive!=false && newActive!=sndList[activeItem]){

        var newSrc= newActive.getAttribute("data-ref");
        togglePlay();
        document.getElementById("audSrc").setAttribute("src", newSrc);
        audEl.load();
        togglePlay("ward");

        newActive.classList.add("active-snd");
        sndList[activeItem].classList.remove("active-snd");

        newActive.parentNode.scrollTop = newActive.offsetHeight*(((wardType=="backward")?activeItem-1
                                        :(wardType=="forward"?activeItem+1:elId))-2);

        newActive.children[0].children[0].rempClass("fa-play","fa-pause");
        sndList[activeItem].children[0].children[0].rempClass("fa-pause","fa-play");

        newActive.children[1].children[1].children[0].rempClass("fa-folder","fa-folder-open");
        sndList[activeItem].children[1].children[1].children[0].rempClass("fa-folder-open","fa-folder");
    }
}

// Resize player element function //
function resizeAud() {
    var playerElment = document.getElementById("player").getBoundingClientRect().width;
    var audElment = document.getElementById("audio").getBoundingClientRect().width;
    if (document.body.getBoundingClientRect().width<=767){
        document.getElementById("snd-list").style.width = "100%";
        document.querySelector(".show-list").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("snd-list").classList.add("mobile-snd-list");
    }else{
        document.getElementById("snd-list").style.width = (playerElment - audElment)+"px";
        document.querySelector(".show-list").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("snd-list").classList.remove("mobile-snd-list");
    }
}

// remplace class by another class //
Element.prototype.rempClass = function(first,second) {
    this.classList.remove(first);
    this.classList.add(second);
};
}
```

[image: Audio player]

as you see i have player interface and playlist menu
in pc audioplayer work fine and can get audio duration & other audio details.
but when i access from phone even audio details cant get.
Thank you all

[Demo](http://aghogha.net/)

Comment: Are you waiting for the audio to load? Also, I cant quite work out from your code, but I guess you know that e.g. IOS won't play sound automatically? Are you able to make a more minimal snippet that shows the problem?

Comment: the audio dont play, only i loaded it automatically after DOMContentLoaded.
the snippet will not work i think because the source is in my localhost.
Thank you for replying

Comment: but i will upload it to a server

Comment: i add a demo link on the content